# How do I conditionally render an icon based on the value of a prop?

Tags: reactjs

**Goal**: To conditionally render the appropriate icon for attendance statuses (default, present, excused, absent).

**Problem**: I am having trouble using the state in a conditional statement to return the proper icon.

It seems that the first thing that happens is, in componentDidMount(), the state of 'status' is set to what the prop is. The last thing that happens, as shown in the console logs, is that this.state.status is "excused" which is correct - so it seems the state is properly being set? But I'm confused about why everything that happens in between does not reflect that. At the conditional statement, I am unable to capture the state to figure out which icon should be returned.

I've tried to do research but I am new to React and also kind of unsure how to word my problem in a way that my search would return the answers I need so I hope that makes sense. Your feedback is appreciated!

**Code:**

```
class StudentDisplay extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            status: ""
        }
        this.checkStatus = this.checkStatus.bind(this)
    }

    checkStatus = currentStatus => {

        console.log(`checkStatus()... `)
        console.log(`currentStatus = ${currentStatus}`);

        // temporary conditional statement for testing
        if (currentStatus === "") {
            console.log(`... currentStatus === blank`)
        } else if (currentStatus === "excused") {
            console.log(`... currentStatus === excused`)
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {

        console.log(`componentDidMount()...`)

        this.setState({
            status: this.props.status
        })

        let currentStatus = this.state.status
        console.log(`let currentStatus = this.state.status`)
        console.log(`currentStatus = ${currentStatus}`)
        console.log(`this.state.status = ${this.state.status}`)

        this.checkStatus(currentStatus);
        console.log(`this.checkStatus( ${currentStatus} )`);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="card card-body">
                {console.log(`render()... `)}
                {console.log(`and this.state.status = ${this.state.status}`)}
                <h2 className="text-center">{this.state.status}</h2>
            </div>

            // default icon = <i className="fas fa-question-circle"></i>
            // present icon = <i className="fas fa-user-check"></i>
            // excused icon = <i className="fas fa-user-minus"></i>
            // absent icon = <i className="fas fa-user-slash"></i>
        )
    }
}
```

**Console logs**:

render()...

and this.state.status =

---

componentDidMount()...

let currentStatus = this.state.status

currentStatus =

this.state.status =

---

checkStatus()...

currentStatus =

... currentStatus === blank

this.checkStatus(  )

---

render()...

and this.state.status = excused

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems that the first thing that happens is, in componentDidMount(),
>   the state of 'status' is set to what the prop is. The last thing that
>   happens, as shown in the console logs, is that this.state.status is
>   "excused" which is correct - so it seems the state is properly being
>   set? But I'm confused about why everything that happens in between
>   does not reflect that.

Everything between what? Seems like it updated correctly.

React state updates are asynchronous, meaning you can call setState many times within a function/render cycle and they are all "collected" and run when the current render cycle is complete. This is part of react's reconciliation process. If you wish to see the outcome of updating your react state then you need to pass a callback to the `setState` function, the second argument.

I.E.

```
setState({ newState }, () => console.log('This is the new state', this.state));
```

When you call `checkStatus` you are still working with the "current" state value, not the one you're queueing up for update.

**Suggestion**

I don't recommend duplicating props into state, though, it's actually an anti-pattern, just put that logic directly in the render function. I suggest using a switch statement to select which icon you want to display.

```
render() {
  const { status } = this.props;
  let icon = null;

  switch (status) {
    case 'present':
      icon = <i className="fas fa-user-check" />;
      break;

    case 'excused':
      icon = <i className="fas fa-user-minus" />;
      break;

    case 'absent':
      icon = <i className="fas fa-user-slash" />;
      break;

    default:
      icon = <i className="fas fa-question-circle" />;
      break;
  }

  return (
    <div className="card card-body">
      <h2 className="text-center">{this.state.status}</h2>
      {icon}
    </div>
  )
}
```